# This code is not submitting to a form? Why

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

Since I am using get I expect to see the submitted values appended to the queryString but instead all I see is the URL of the servlet being called with nothing added at the end.

```
<form id="editClassList" name="editClassList" method="get" action="EditClassList">
<%
 HashMap<Integer,String> classes = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
 classes = (HashMap<Integer,String>) request.getAttribute("classes");
%>
<% 
  if(classes.size()==0){ %>
    <label><input class="small-link" type="text" id="add-this-class"
                  size="42" value="" /></label>  
<%
 }
%>
<%
  Set<Integer> classIds = new HashSet<Integer>();
  classIds = classes.keySet();
  Iterator<Integer> itr = classIds.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
      int nextId = (Integer)itr.next();
%>
  <label><input class="small-link" type="text" id="<% out.print(nextId); %>"
                size="42" value="<% out.print(classes.get(nextId)); %>" />
  </label> 
  <img id="add-class" src="images/add.png" width="16" height="16" /><br />
  <label><input class="small-link" type="text" id="class-to-add"
        size="42" value="" /></label>  
<%
  }
%>
<label><input type="submit" id="save-class-btn" value="Save Class(es)" /></label>
</form>
```

Comment: @Ankur: I have reformatted your code to avoid scrollbars, but you could still improve it by correcting indentation (and using spaces instead of tabs).

Comment: @Bozho - that was a good suggestion, but I used PeterMmm's suggestion and that worked, hence didn't respond to your request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A try: your input tags lacks the **name** attribute ?

```
<input name="data" class="small-link" type="text" id="class-to-add" size="42" value="" />
```